# What is the port with the red cap for on my generator?

Tags: generator

I have a (2005 - 2007) Briggs & Stratton 5,550 Watt Portable Generator - Model Number 030324 Rev Number 00.

I'm in the process of preparing it for shipment and I was instructed to leave it dry. After examining the generator I noticed the oil dip stick which is pretty long (4 inches maybe) and has a yellow cap as expected. However, closer to the bottom of the generator there is a red cap that's about a inch long that has fluid in it. The fluid appears reddish/pinkish. Nothing in the manual points to what it could potentially be.

What is this fluid?

I want to ensure when shipping the generator I ship new bottles of the fluid. Also, does anyone know what type of oil the generator takes and what spark plug?

Comment: @Harper When I said "Nothing in the manual points to what it could potentially be." I thought it implied that I could not find what I asked in the forum in the manual. I'll close the question because I found the answers to my question. 10W - 30 or 5W-30 depending on the temperature. Also, the spark plug seems like a standard small engine Briggs and Stratton one that you can get from Home depot .The red cap is also the oil cap. I think it allows for pouring the oil through a funnel. Granted you can do that through the dip stick but I guess there is a mechanical reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

The red cap is for the oil too. I'm guessing it allows for a funnel to be used and that's the preferred place to add the oil.

The oil type is either 5W - 30 or 10 - 30. And the spark plug is standard I'm guessing based on a Home Depot run and internet search.